# A query on Hibernate database design

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design, jersey

I am writing a simple web application where I have a User entity and set of pre-defined questions to be answered by the User. The answers provided by the users for these questions would need to be stored against the userId and questionId. After a bit of googling and with the help of stackoverflow, I have designed the tables in the following way.

```
UserDetails(userId, userName)
QuestionMaster(questionId, question)
QuestionAnswer(userId, questionId, answer, date) PK(userId, questionId)
```

The Hibernate Entity classes:

**UserDetails.class**

```
@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class UserDetails {

private int userId;
private String userName;
private Collection<QuestionAnswer> listOfAnswers = new HashSet<QuestionAnswer>();

@XmlElement (name = "answer", type=QuestionAnswer.class)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.userDetails", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Collection<QuestionAnswer> getListOfAnswers() {
    return listOfAnswers;
}

public void setListOfAnswers(Collection<QuestionAnswer> listOfAnswers) {
    this.listOfAnswers = listOfAnswers;
}

@XmlElement (name = "userId")
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

@XmlElement (name = "userName")
@Column(nullable=false)
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
}
```

**QuestionMaster.class**

```
@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name="question")
public class QuestionMaster {

private int questionId;
private String question;
private Collection<QuestionAnswer> listOfAnswers = new HashSet<QuestionAnswer>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.questionMaster", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Collection<QuestionAnswer> getListOfAnswers() {
    return listOfAnswers;
}

public void setListOfAnswers(Collection<QuestionAnswer> listOfAnswers) {
    this.listOfAnswers = listOfAnswers;
}

@XmlElement(name="quesId")
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getQuestionId() {
    return questionId;
}

public void setQuestionId(int questionId) {
    this.questionId = questionId;
}

@XmlElement(name="ques")
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}   
}
```

**QuestionAnser.class**

```
@Entity
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.questionMaster", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTIONID", nullable = false)),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.userDetails", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USERID", nullable = false)) })
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "answer")
public class QuestionAnswer {
private String answer;
private Date date;
private QuestionAnswerId pk = new QuestionAnswerId();

@EmbeddedId
public QuestionAnswerId getPk() {
    return pk;
}

@XmlElement (name = "question", type=QuestionMaster.class)
@Transient
public QuestionMaster getQuestionMaster(){
    return getPk().getQuestionMaster();
}

public void setQuestionMaster(QuestionMaster questionMaster){
    getPk().setQuestionMaster(questionMaster);
}

@Transient
public UserDetails getUserDetails(){
    return getPk().getUserDetails();
}


public void setUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails){
    getPk().setUserDetails(userDetails);
}

public void setPk(QuestionAnswerId pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
}

@XmlElement(name="ans")
@Column(nullable=false)
public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}

@XmlElement(name="date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "DATE", nullable = false, length = 10)
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date){
    this.date = date;
}

}
```

**QuestionAnswerId.class**

```
@Embeddable
public class QuestionAnswerId implements Serializable {

private QuestionMaster questionMaster;
private UserDetails userDetails;

@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public QuestionMaster getQuestionMaster() {
    return questionMaster;
}

public void setQuestionMaster(QuestionMaster questionMaster) {
    this.questionMaster = questionMaster;
}

@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public UserDetails getUserDetails() {
    return userDetails;
}

public void setUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails) {
    this.userDetails = userDetails;
}
}
```

Sample REST API output for: /rest/users/5

```
<user>
    <userName>xyz</userName>
    <userId>5</userId>
    <answer>
        <ans>xyz</ans>
        <date>2013-12-18T00:00:00+05:30</date>
        <question>
            <ques>What is your name</quesId>
            <quesId>5</quesId>
        </question>
    </answer>
    <answer>
        <ans>25</ans>
        <date>2013-12-18T00:00:00+05:30</date>
        <question>
            <ques>What is your age</ques>
            <quesId>6</quesId>
        </question>
    </answer>
</user>
```

You comments/suggestions on this database design will be highly appreciated. I am new to Hibernate and in the process the learning it. Please suggest whether there is a better way to design the user-question-answer relationship, so that the response XML looks more elegant.

Comment: you have no place to store the correct answer for each question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my scenario, the questions could be like "whats your hobby, game" etc. Am in the process of building a guessing game... where, the counterparts will be asked to guess the person with the help of these hints(answers to these questions). So there wouldn't be anything like correct answer, the answer provided by each user is stored in the QuestionAnswer table.. maybe it should renamed to UserAnswer??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should avoid composite IDs like the plague. Use an auto-generated single-column ID for all your entities, and everything will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have now posted the question on codereview.stackexchange.com.